# Can viruses be spread via VGA cables?

Tags: video, virus, cable

Are VGA cables too "dumb" to spread malware from one device to another device?

**Background**: I'm giving a talk tomorrow, and the laptop I'm presenting on will be connected via VGA cable to another computer that'll be recording the presentation as well as passing the signal to a projector. Not that I have any reason to believe my computer or the other computer are likely to have viruses...

Comment: How do you connect 2 pc's with a vga cable?? A pc usually doesn't have a vga-in.

Comment: @Andrew, your profile says you analyse biological data. Sounds fascinating, but remember, the 'computer virus' *metaphor* can only be stretched *so far*.

Comment: @pavium when I talk about mutation testing to rails developers, they assume I'm talking about genetic diseases rather than unit testing because I'm a bioinformatician.

Comment: bwahahahahahaha.  i guess if you can network 2 PCs with a VGA cable, you can certainly transfer viruses....

Comment: A good reason to not put VGA cables in your mouth!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, they cannot be spread via VGA.

Comment: Expanding on that, I'd like to say that the recording device is only receiving the video signal from your laptop. No actual harddrive data is being transmitted.

Answer (score 21):

In theory, yes, it might be possible for a display to exploit a weakness in the computer's display drivers via the [DDC backlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel). In parctice, I have never heard about such an exploit being used.

Comment: Seems farfetched, but at one time viruses spreading via e-mail was a big joke amongst IT professionals since it was "impossible".  Look at us now...

Comment: +1 Cool idea. Somebody should exploit it, seriously.

Comment: If this was a typically use case I'm sure we would see it, but since almost nobody does this I doubt we ever will.

Comment: Data is being transmitted by the monitor to the PC, letting the PC know what type of monitor it is.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this has now been done, but with HDMI rather than VGA. Someone found a bunch of HDMI CEC and HEC handling bugs in a few mobile devices and demonstrated how it was possible to gain remote root on them just by plugging in a malicious device.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by Toby is correct, under normal circumstances you would not be able to get a virus from a vga connection.....  but this does given me an idea for a funny office prank.

Open up a dvi-vga adapter and incorporate a device that flashes the word virus on the screen for 2-5 frames every 5 minutes.

Instant Classic

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, similar to @Kythos' prank, would be to place a hardware keylogger together with this display spoofer, and make it display something on the screen like a windows logon.